# Errors installing -g node-gyp on OSX El Capitan

Tags: javascript, macos, terminal, arduino, johnny-five

I'm trying to install johnny-five to run Arduino Uno through JS. I keep getting stuck on `npm install -g node-gyp`. This seems to be a common issue, but none of the threads I've found have proven helpful.

I'm very new to all of this, so please over-explain.

Most of my errors seem to be permissions errors. For reference, I'm running Xcode 8.1 and Node.js 6.9.1. and Python 2.7.

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "node-gyp"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/juliefunk/libtool-2.4.2/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: use sudo npm install ... to give it the needed permissions

Comment: This is a package written in c++ that needs to be compild, for that you need root permissions, like for every native package

Comment: You also need sudo for packages you install global, because of the location of them is in the folder where node is installed (typicaly /usr/local)

Comment: Great!  `sudo` worked. But when I try to run a js sketch I get the following syntax error.   

`SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token  
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)  
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)  
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)  
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)  
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)  
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)  
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)  
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)  
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)  
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3`

Comment: Is there no file and line number above this Error message that shows where the error occurs? I think you simply  have a syntax error in your script. Maybe run a blink sketch to verify that your setup is working.

Comment: @Julian

The file line above is  `/Users/juliefunk/libtool-2.4.2/nodebot/ledtest.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf470`

Comment: looks like an rtf file with your module transformed to an function, but i dont know where this could come from. Did you try the blinking led http://johnny-five.io/examples/. This would proof the error is in your code and not somewhere else